# Functions couldn't called functions due to their declaration order (c++)

Tags: c++, function

I have searched topics but I couldn't fin the answer.

I have 2 functions e.g

```
int login_call, main_call;

// main screen //
void mainscreen(int x)
{
loginscreen(login_call);
}


// login screen //
void loginscreen(int y)
{
mainscreen(main_call);
}
```

My question is that I am calling out login screen in main screen and main screen in login screen but it doesn't work because when first function is parsed first, an error comes that your loginscreen is not declared.. and when I switch the positions of these 2 functions above, error comes that mainscreen is not declared. Please suggest me the ways to call functions which doesn't depend upon the order of declarations.

Thanks!

Comment: why not add a [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)?

Answer (score 3):

Forward declaration:

```
int login_call, main_call;

void loginscreen(int);

void mainscreen(int x)
{
    loginscreen(login_call);
}

void loginscreen(int y)
{
    mainscreen(main_call);
}
```

You'll need to figure out a way to end this infinite recursion, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a function before it is defined:

```
int login_call, main_call;

//declare login screen function here so mainscreen() can call it
void loginscreen(int y);

// main screen //
void mainscreen(int x)
{
    loginscreen(login_call);
}


// login screen //
void loginscreen(int y)
{
    mainscreen(main_call);
}
```

Comment: This isn't correct. I have tried your way but this never helps because compiler (dev++) says that you couldn't declare again as you have done it.

Comment: You can declare a function as many times as you like but only define it once.  Declarations end with a `;` and definitions end with a function body `{ some(); code(); here(); }`.   Can you post the code with the declaration that doesn't work for you?